# Why is this callback not called asynchronously

Tags: javascript, callback

The function asyncMsg is called immediately on clicking the start hooking button.  How do I change to call only when user clicks on press me button.  I need to pass the 2 items of data into this callback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">

function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
   if (el.addEventListener){
      el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false); 
   } else if (el.attachEvent){
      el.attachEvent('on'+eventName, eventHandler);
   }
}

function asyncMsg(data, fldid) {
   alert("asynchronous message with param1=" + data + " param2=" + fldid);
}

function dohooking() {
   var toinsert = "Duck";
   var fldid = "10";
   var btn = document.getElementById("hookee");
   bindEvent(btn, 'click', asyncMsg(toinsert, fldid));
}

</script>

<title></title>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="sethooking" value="start hooking" onclick="dohooking();">
<br />

<input type="button" id="hookee" value="press me">
<br />

</body>
</html>
```

I can see how if I just pass the function as in:

```
bindEvent(btn, 'click', asyncMsg);
```

then it is called asynchronously, but then how do I pass the 2 parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the function immediately instead of passing the function itself to the `bindEvent` function - because calling the function is what happens when you use the `()` "operator" on a function.

What you want instead is this:

```
bindEvent(btn, 'click', asyncMsg.bind(null, toinsert, fldid));
```

The [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method of a function returns another callable that will execute the function with the given context (`null` in this case) and the provided parameters.

Another option that also works in older browsers would be creating an anonymous function which then calls your function:

```
bindEvent(btn, 'click', function() {
    asyncMsg(toinsert, fldid);
});
```

Comment: Note: when using bind like that, the event object will be passed at arguments[2], instead of the usual first argument.